# docx remains a template file after mail merge with docx4j

Tags: docx4j

Using the examples, I've manage to get my merge fields properly replaced with test data. However, when I open the output file in Word, it still asks for the mailmerge.mer file and the character encoding, as if it were still a template.

Obviously, there is a step I am missing, but the docx4j documentation doesn't mention it nor do the examples contain it.

I want the output.docx to open without further mailmerge functionality, it should be a regular word file.

my code, unexciting as it is:

```
public class FieldsMailMerge {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File("test-input.docx"));

    Map<DataFieldName, String> map = new HashMap<DataFieldName, String>();
    map.put( new DataFieldName("Name"), "Daffy duck");
    map.put( new DataFieldName("Test"), "Plutext");
    map.put(new DataFieldName("NR"), "12345");

    org.docx4j.model.fields.merge.MailMerger.performMerge(wordMLPackage, map, true);
    wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("test-output.docx"));
}
```

}

Comment: You mean if you go into the Mail menu in Word, you see the "Select Recipients" not greyed out?  If something else, please describe and post your docx somewhere.

Comment: I mean if I open the .docx that I created, it asks for the data file, as if it were a template, not an output file.

Comment: Please post your sample input docx somewhere